# Is there a way to attatch a css file to a jEditorPane?

Tags: html, css, swing, jeditorpane

Simple enough question: I have a string containing HTML that is being handed off to a JEditorPane for user consumption.

Can I attach a CSS file (or string containing CSS rules) to allow for more specific styling of the text?

Answer (score 4):

The `HTMLEditorKit` per default looks for a file `default.css` - I'm not sure where, though.

Alternatively, this should work:

```
StyleSheet ss = new StyleSheet();
ss.importStyleSheet(styleSheetURL);
HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit)jEditorPane.getEditorKit();
kit.setStyleSheet(ss);
```

However, note that HTMLEditorKit only supports a [limited subset](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html) of CSS 1.

Comment: Editor kits are actually shared across multiple editor panes (which doesn't appear to be mentioned in the API, but if you read the source code you'll see it.)  So this code will actually change every JEditorPane in the application, rather than the specific one you want to style.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just include a style tag along with the HTML content in `setText()`?

e.g.

```
jEditorPane.setText( "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">...</style></head><body>...");
```