# Handling CSS and JavaScript when building a Java browser

Tags: java, browser

My task is to create a simple web browser in Java. 
So far it can only read HTML pages.
I'm using standard JEditorPane component to display webpages.

Now I was wondering is there any way you could explain me how can I manage to display at least some simple pages that contain CSS/Javascript. 
If you could point me to some useful links or appropriate examples I would be very happy.

Comment: Some might argue that a **simple** web browser does not need support JavaScript or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There alrady is some prior art for the Java browser segment.

concerning javascript, you will have to use a javascript interpreter in Java. A renowned one is [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (by Mozilla). Its integration may reveals to be an interesting challenge.

concerning CSS, it seems the question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436120/is-there-a-way-to-attatch-a-css-file-to-a-jeditorpane) ...

Comment: I've been searching for it but I found nothing on stackoverflow.
Thanks for your contribution

Comment: Then consider checking the "answser" check beside my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, my advice would be to look at open source rendering engines such as Gecko - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_FAQ

You can embed Gecko with Java using the JREX library - http://jrex.mozdev.org/

Starting from scratch with a problem like this is a very big task, and as your username is AmateurProgrammer, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: lol, you're damn right.
Thanx for your reply, I'll look into it.