# How could I create a start page for my Java application much like Netbeans start page?

Tags: java, html, components

It appears the start page is an html document rendered somehow. I know about jWebPane, but its dead and the only other active solution I can find is to embed firefox which is a huge dependency and eats up a ton of memory. Is there any lightweight solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JEditorPane` is the built in Java webpage viewer. It's not a full blown browser but it should do the trick!

The nice part is that it will let you handle link clicks, for instance you could open a screen of you application when the user clicks a link.

CSS seems to be partially supported according to this [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436120/is-there-a-way-to-attatch-a-css-file-to-a-jeditorpane)

Comment: What about CSS or JS? It appears I can load HTML, but the NetBeans start page has link roll over effects as well as a tab gui much like a javascript tab setup.